# Windows Variant Coercion Rules?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, variant, coercion

I have a Windows [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx) holding a BSTR with a (supposedly) numeric value.

I want to use [`VariantChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221258(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert this BSTR value to a VT_I4 or VT_I8 or ...

To my surprise, passing in a string value of `"5.6"`, `.` being my decimal separator, the function succeeds for integer conversion, and the resulting `lVal`or `llVal` value is `6`! I would have expected either a conversion error, or a value of `5`, which is what `sscanf` gives me.

`-->` **Is there any documentation for the conversion rules used by the [VARIANT conversion functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221508(v=vs.85).aspx)?** `<--`

I found that `VariantChangeType` is implemented through (e.g.) [`VarI4FromStr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221194(v=vs.85).aspx), but there is *zero* info wrt. the conversion rules used by this function.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9fee1107-957b-403c-86c1-f42ccfb88f50/windows-variant-coercion-rules

Comment: From MSDN: "... it appears that VarI4FromStr and VariantChangeType round the value up or down during the conversion.  For example "5.4" is converted to 5."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be any documentation with regard to this.

From the [linked MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9fee1107-957b-403c-86c1-f42ccfb88f50/windows-variant-coercion-rules) and a bit of debugging, I can conclude:

- `VariantChangeType` does call the Data Type Conversion Functions (as noted)
- `VarI4FromStr` seems to call `VarR8FromStr` internally - this explains how we have rounding
- `VarR*FromStr` seems to call [`VarParseNumFromStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-varparsenumfromstr)
- `VarParseNumFromStr` does *not* seem to further delegate the numeric parsing itself (quick test of mine in VS2010); it doesn't document any parsing rules AFAIK.
- Rounding seems to use [Round Half to Even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) or some variation.