# VarI4FromStr broken at lowest long value on ARM64?

Tags: c++, ole, arm64, integer-overflow, bstr

The following code is fine on regular x64 Windows.

```
const LCID LOCALE_EN_US = MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US), SORT_DEFAULT);
long val;
BSTR str = SysAllocString(L"-2147483648"));
if (VarI4FromStr(str, LOCALE_EN_US,0,&val) == S_OK)
{
  //False on arm64, true on regular x64
}
SysFreeString(str);
```

However, on arm64 VarI4FromStr returns DISP_E_OVERFLOW. This seems very strange, especially since the following:

```
short val;
BSTR str = SysAllocString(L"-32768"));
if (VarI2FromStr(str, LOCALE_EN_US,0,&val) == S_OK)
{
  //True on arm64
}
SysFreeString(str);
```

which seems to be doing the exact same thing for 2 bytes, works fine. It also works fine with positive 2147483647.

Comment: Related: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48786387/65863) for how `VarI4FromStr()` works.  I don't know if `VarI2FromStr()` follows similar rules or not.

Comment: @HansPassant I expanded the code to include the definition of LOCALE_EN_US, sorry for the omission. It's being run in a googletest. That's it, there really isn't anything else to the code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I had seen that. Fwiw, the documentation for VarParseNumFromStr() [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-varparsenumfromstr?redirectedfrom=MSDN) seems to indicate that `VarI2FromStr()` uses it as well as `VarI4FromStr()`.